# skip validation after create mongoid rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, skip

I want to skip a validation after an object is created. Lets take an example

person has many company and company has many people

person has many placements and placement belongs to person
person can have only one active placement

Placement model has one validation that checks if a person already has an active placement when saved.

```
@placement is active placement
@employment.placement = @person

if @placement.save
  #################
  @person.placements << @placement
  @company.placements << @placement
end
```

Now when the placement is saved for the first time, No problem its gets saved.

Now the problem comes when

```
@person.placements << @placement
```

Since the person already has  active placement through @placement.save.

@person.placements << @placement again saves @placement and the validation fires validation error to @placement object.

Is there any way so that i tell not to go through that specific validation some where in ############ region of my code.

Or any alternative solutions are welcome.

Thanks

Comment: You should accept the answer if it worked for you. Give the guy his points. :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

you can use: save :validate => false

Comment: But how do you **save :validate => false** while using << operator as it saves both @company and @placements at once? Any idea

Comment: just save the placement first (with validate false), then add it to your company

Answer (score 1):

The first thing if you want to save after all the validations passes then do something like this

```
if @placement.valid?
  @person.placements << @placement
  @company.placements << @placement
end
```

Next thing is if you are using mongoid then `<<` operator call `.save` on  both documents.

The solution may be either overwrite `<<` of mongoid, Or need to speacify validation during which action.

`validates :placeholder, :on => :create` And Or

```
if @placement.valid?
  @placement.person = @person
  @company.placements << @placement
end
```